# Solve $y’+ \frac{y}{t}=3\cos(t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I’m trying to Solve $y’+ \frac{y}{t}=3\cos(t)$ .

My Try :
Solving the homogeneous equation:
$y_h \rightarrow  y’=-\frac{y}{t} \rightarrow y=-C \cdot t$

Solving the p equation :

Assuming :

$y=-t \cdot C(t)$

We get :

$y’=-C(t)-t \cdot C(t)’$

I’ll plug these in the equation:

$y_p \rightarrow -C(t)-t \cdot C(t)’ - C(t) =3\cos(t)$

Which I just get back to :

$ -t\cdot C(t)’-2C(t)=3\cos(t)$

Which I’m not able to solve for C(t) .

I would like to get an idea of what I’m doing wrong and an idea of the solution.

Comment: All solutions are right, but they fail to point out the OP's mistake in the solution of the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

I would recommend you to multiply both sides by $t$:

\begin{align*}
y' + \frac{y}{t} = 3\cos(t) & \Longleftrightarrow ty' + y = 3t\cos(t)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ty)' = 3t\cos(t)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**

If we integrate by parts, we achieve the desired result:
\begin{align*}
ty & = \int 3t\cos(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
& = 3t\sin(t) - 3\int\sin(t)\mathrm{d}t\\\
& = 3t\sin(t) + 3\cos(t) + c
\end{align*}

Comment: I do get the same $y_h=C\cdot t$ but my issue is rather with $y_p$ , would appreciate if you could further your explanation!

Comment: @Losh_EE I edited my answer. Tell me if you need further assistance.

Comment: Understood , may I ask if you can give me an idea of why my solution doesn’t solve it or how I can do the solution through the formal $y(t)=y_h +y_p$ way ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We have the inhomogeneous linear differential equation:
$$
y'(t) + p(t) y(t) = q(t),\quad\quad\quad\quad(1)
$$
where $p(t) = \dfrac{1}{t}$ and $q(t) = 3 \cos(t)$. Solution of (1) can be represented in an exact analytical form
$$
y(t) = \exp\left(-\int\limits_{t_0}^t p(\tau) d\tau\right) \left(y_0 + \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} q(\tau) \exp\left(\int\limits_{t_0}^\tau p(\xi) d\xi\right) d\tau\right),\quad\quad\quad\quad(2)
$$
where $t_0$ is any constant form the domain of definition, $y_0$ is the constant of integration.

Let us choose $t_0 = 1$ and calculate (2)
$$
y(t) = \frac{3 t \sin (t)+3 \cos (t)+y_0-3 (\sin (1)+\cos (1))}{t}
$$
or
$$
y(t) = \frac{3 t \sin (t)+3 \cos (t)+ C}{t}
$$
where $C$ is an arbitrary real constant.

Comment: I do not think learning formula (2) is particularly pedagogical.

Comment: @Miguel, Well, but what we can do when almost all students have problems with such equations? No matter what methods are explained to them, students will always make mistakes. So we have to just show the formula. After that, teaching becomes easier. By the way, this is a quite general method that does not depend on specific functions and examples.

Answer (score 1):

$$y’+ \frac{y}{t}=3cos(t)$$
Solve the homogeneous DE:
$$y’+ \frac{y}{t}=0$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y}=-\dfrac 1t$$
$$(\ln y)'=-\dfrac 1t$$
$$\ln y =-\ln t+C$$
$$y_h(t)=\dfrac Ct$$
Solve the inhomogeneous DE now.
$$y(t)=\dfrac {C(t)}t$$
$$y’+ \frac{y}{t}=3cos(t)$$
$$\dfrac {tC'-C}{t^2}+ \frac{C}{t^2}=3cos(t)$$
This DE is separable.
$$C'=3tcos(t)$$
Integrate.
$$C(t)=3t\sin(t)+3\cos t +c$$

Answer (score 1):

Although all answers are correct, I would like to elaborate on the OP's mistake and *why* (IMHO) it has occurred.

The homogeneous equation is:
$$
y'=-\frac{y}{t}
$$

It is obviously separable, but let us do it very carefully using the **Leibniz notation**:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{y}{t}
$$
so that
$$
\frac{dy}{y}=-\frac{dt}{t}
$$
which, after integration, leads us to
$$
\ln y=-\ln t +C
$$
This equation is solved for $y$ by applying the exponential:
$$
\begin{aligned}
y&=e^{-\ln t +C}\\&=e^C\,e^{-\ln t}\\&=e^C\,e^{\ln t^{-1}}\\&=e^C\,t^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

So the mistake is a quick and wrong assumption that $-\ln t=\ln( -t)$.